# Does git care about its relative location?

Tags: git

For example, I do a git init on a file called `root-foo` and use this as my working directory.

Later I move this folder to another location does git care in any way.

I've done this and I see no effects.  However I just want to make sure their are no quirks I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely move the folder. There is a hidden `.git` directory inside the root folder. As long as that `.git` directory is present, you are fine moving it and so forth.

Comment: @cadegalt Do you mean above the parent of the .git directory? If that is the question, I can't think of any times that it does. The only time I've had relative directories matter is if I'm down in a child directory, had a file change up above, and did a `git add .` to add all changed files. That only captures the files in current directory and down. Otherwise, I don't think there are many commands that are relative.